# How to get MacVim to recognize python_fn.vim?

Tags: python, vim, macvim

I downloaded python_fn.vim from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=30

The instructions say: "Save this file to $VIMFILES/ftplugin/python.vim. You can have multiple
" python ftplugins by creating $VIMFILES/ftplugin/python and saving your
" ftplugins in that directory."

So would I put it into ~/.vimfiles/ftplugin and then rename it python.vim ?

Comment: The best advice for this sort of thing: try it! It's trivial enough to do, you don't need to ask others.

Answer (score 1):

Never used it, but I'd suggest putting it at `~/.vim/ftplugin/python/python_fn.vim` and see if it works.  This will allow you to have multiple python ftplugins.

Note that `$VIMFILES` is not `~/.vimfiles`.